# When to branch, tag & merge in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, branching-and-merging

When should one branch/tag in Mercurial (`hg`), both at the local repo level and at the centralized/originating repo (that you `hg clone`)? When should you merge (again at the local level and in the central repo)?

I come from a SVN background where branches were used for new features ("*feature branches*"), as well as "*release branches*". In the case of feature branches, a developer would create a branch if he/she knew a project was going to span multiple sprints/releases. The feature branch would then be merged back in once the developer was certain they'd be releasing the new feature during the given sprint. The release branch would then be created and deployed to QA and a staging environemnt for QAT/UAT testing respectively. Any bugs that arose during testing would be committed directly to the release branch. When the release branch was finally ready to be released, it would be tagged (for archival/record-keeping purposes) and then finally, after the release branch was deployed live, it would be merged back with trunk.

How does this process change with a DVCS such as `hg`?

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 1):

Branching|merging policy *can* does not differ at all. These processes just give less headache in Mercurial (you will not be a victim of "Refactoring Hell" with a minimal level of accuracy, unfamous Tree Conflicts are also history) - DVCS vs CVCS will change almost nothing here, Mercurial give you just more freedom: branch when|if you want

Comment: Thanks @Lazy Badger (+1) - is there a concept of branching/tagging at the central/originating repo level vs branching/tagging at the local repo level? For instance, if Developer A clones a repo locally, and then branches it, and then commits/pushes that branch to the central server; then can I "pull down" that branch/tag? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja - "is there a concept of branching/tagging at the central/originating repo level vs branching/tagging at the local repo level?" No. You just *create branch in repository* and *publish it*, in *any* applicable form. FYou can get new branch|tag from "central repo" and can (under some conditions) can ignore these nodes